# Inserting data into a SQL Server database from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I'm trying to insert data (user input) into a SQL Server database. Everything looks fine but it's not actually inserting any data into the database. Code behind file (`default.aspx.cs`) looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mumsDiaryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    protected void reg_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            // storing user input data into variable
            var first = reg_first.Text;
            var last = reg_last.Text; 
            var email = reg_email.Text;
            var pass = reg_pass.Text.GetHashCode().ToString();
            var sub = reg_sub.Text;
            var state = reg_state.Text;
            var post = reg_post.Text;
            var country = "Australia";

            try  
            {
                 connection.Open();
                 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO user(first, last, email, password, suburb, postcode, state, country) VALUES('"+first+"','"+last+"','"+email+"','"+pass+"','"+sub+"','"+post+"','"+state+"','"+country+"')", connection);
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                Label10.Text = "something gone wrong";
                Label10.Text += err.Message;        
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
                //  Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Home_page.aspx");
            }
      }
 }
}
```

this is my web.config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433-->

<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="mumsDiaryConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=MDASHIFURRA73C7\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mumsDiary;Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
</system.web>

<appSettings>
  <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

can anyone identify what is the problem here? cheers.

Comment: and the error you get is?

Comment: have you used the debugger to step through the code..? are you getting any errors

Comment: This code is bad. Please don't write it like this. It's vulnerable to SQL injection. Rewrite with parameterized query.

Comment: If you are not seeing the error text maybe the Page.IsValid is false. Try stepping through the code and make sure the try block is reached.

Comment: `cmd` needs disposing also, same for `connection` if you not doing it elsewhere (you probably shouldn't be)

Comment: In addition to the textbook example of a sql injection vulnerability you also are storing passwords in plain text. This is also a big no no. They should be salted and hashed.

Comment: 1) im not getting any error at all.@Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani
2)debug result:
The thread 0x1e98 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1900 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x17dc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x66c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xf10 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[5916] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).@MethodMan
3)has disposed both of them@Alex K
4)i already hashed but hasn't done the salting part. before that need to make sure data has being inserted correctly into database.@Sean Lange

Comment: just an update which makes no sense the catch part executed and the error it shows "something gone wrongIncorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'."  in my database this is table description : 
Name    :  user 
Schema:  dbo
System object: false
should i change system object to true. ??

Comment: `User` is a reserved word in SQL Server. I'd recommend you to change the name of the table, otherwise the same error might be happening quite often.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly we don't have enough information to correctly diagnose your issue, from what I can see these are potential issues and security flaws.  Your query should be structured more like:

```
private readonly string dbConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString[".."].ConnectionString;
private const string queryInsertUser = "INSERT INTO [User] ([FirstName]) VALUES (@FirstName);"

protected void SaveUser(string firstName)
{
     using(var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection))
     using(var command = new SqlCommand(queryInsertUser, connection))
     {
          connection.Open();
          command.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = first;
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

So the above would prevent the Sql Injection that you would introduce, you can obtain great articles for Salt / Hash of user password's on the web.  As for your other issue, you'll want to check the following:

- When you run a trace, do you see the query hit your Sql Instance?
- When you step through your code, does it hit enter the `catch` block?
- Is your Sql instance actually running, does it allow your application's user account to run?

Based on the code, though it isn't "standard practice", it should work.  So I believe your issue stems from your Sql Express `ConnectionString` or the instance itself.  Without more information, it will be hard to correctly diagnose, but a trace will reveal if you're correctly hitting the database.

Comment: much appreciate mate. I'm new to programming. still lot of things to learn. anyway  step through code worked great. and been able to determine the problem. thanks for the help. @Greg